# SQL Server - BCP: How to Import CSV File ignoring Double Quotes

Tags: sql-server, bcp, azure-sql-server

I have a csv file with 2 columns

1. LastName
2. FirstName

I am using BCP to load the data into Azure sqlserver table with format file.

I am using the following command to generate the format

> bcp Database.Schema.Persons format nul -c -t, -f Persons.fmt -S tcp:demo.database.windows.net -U User01 -P P@$$word!

It has following format

```
13.0
2
1       SQLCHAR             0       255     ","      1     LastName               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       255     "\r\n"   2     FirstName              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

I could load the data using the below command

> bcp Database.Schema.Persons in "W:\test_load_data.csv" -t , -f Persons.fmt -S tcp:demo.database.windows.net -U User01 -P P@$$word!

**Issue:**
Problem with the .csv file is that FirstName has double quotes around them only when there are multiple words.

**Eg:**

> Karthik,"Vijay"

> Vijay,Karthik

I don't want to include the double quotes while inserting the data into the Azure SQL server.

How should I format the file? or what should I do?

**Note:** I can't have a staging table as explained in   [bcp file sometimes with double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66069923/bcp-file-sometimes-with-double-quotes)

Comment: Are you both exporting and importing using `BCP`? Use native format and save yourself a lot of hassle. No format file. No quote or comma issues. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Have you considered using `BULK INSERT` with the `FORMAT = 'CSV'` parameter instead?

Comment: Can you help me with the sample?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) has plenty of [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#format--csv), including one on [`FORMAT = 'CSV'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#format--csv).

Comment: You know that you can't do this using the approach you chose. You know that there are options that have been discussed and that can be found with simple searching (as you have found). At some point you will need to strip the quote characters - bcp alone will not do this. You decide the path based on your abilities, permissions, goals, etc. Quite frankly, "optional" delimiters will be a problem for most generic importers. Perhaps "cleaning" the new rows after import might work?